# Has anybody used any AOP products under Mono?

Tags: mono, aop, postsharp

I'm looking into using PostSharp on one of my projects. The complicating factor is that I need PostSharp to work on both Windows x64 and Linux x64/Mono.

According to the available info for PostSharp, you can compile on Windows/.NET and run under both .NET and Mono.

The question is this: can I perform PostSharp builds on Linux/Mono?

Answer (score 5):

I can guarantee that PostSharp 2.0 CTP1 Update 1, which I will post tomorrow, supports Mono. It has just been tested on a large code base.

The test setup was a Mac machine.

Comment: This is encouraging. I just need a little more clarification. I don't have a sufficient understanding of PostSharp, so forgive me if the wording is not optimal.

On my project, we have an additional restriction: the build process is equivalent under Linux/Mono and Windows/.NET

If there is a special build step for .NET, it must have an equivalent for Mono.

If PostSharp has a special build step for Windows, is there an equivalent step for Linux/Mono? I can't justify a Windows-only build step.

Thanks

Comment: You'll use the PostSharp nant task or invoke the command line process. This is portable.